# GitLab installation has obscured all the other sites on Apache

Tags: apache-2.2, nginx, ubuntu-16.04, gitlab

I have Apache used also as a reverse proxy for a couple of web applications, both in HTTP and HTTPS, but after installing GitLab, it has obscured them all, and if I go to https://myapp.domain.com I'm always redirected to https://git.domain.com.

The apache config file has not been changed.
If I run lsof I get:

```
user@server:/tmp$ sudo lsof -i :443
user@server:/tmp$ sudo lsof -i :80
COMMAND  PID       USER   FD   TYPE DEVICE SIZE/OFF NODE NAME
nginx   4791       root    7u  IPv4 318350      0t0  TCP *:http (LISTEN)
nginx   4819 gitlab-www    7u  IPv4 318350      0t0  TCP *:http (LISTEN)
nginx   4820 gitlab-www    7u  IPv4 318350      0t0  TCP *:http (LISTEN)
nginx   4821 gitlab-www    7u  IPv4 318350      0t0  TCP *:http (LISTEN)
nginx   4822 gitlab-www    7u  IPv4 318350      0t0  TCP *:http (LISTEN)
```

Apache has gone away:

```
 systemctl status apache2.service
apache2.service - LSB: Apache2 web server
   Loaded: loaded (/etc/init.d/apache2; bad; vendor preset: enabled)
  Drop-In: /lib/systemd/system/apache2.service.d
           └─apache2-systemd.conf
   Active: inactive (dead) since Sat 2019-05-25 15:34:28 CEST; 27min ago
     Docs: man:systemd-sysv-generator(8)
  Process: 1171 ExecStop=/etc/init.d/apache2 stop (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
  Process: 1151 ExecStart=/etc/init.d/apache2 start (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)

May 25 15:34:28 neuron07ubtx apache2[1151]: (98)Address already in use: AH00072: make_sock: could not bind to address [::]:80
May 25 15:34:28 neuron07ubtx apache2[1151]: (98)Address already in use: AH00072: make_sock: could not bind to address 0.0.0.0:80
May 25 15:34:28 neuron07ubtx apache2[1151]: no listening sockets available, shutting down
May 25 15:34:28 neuron07ubtx apache2[1151]: AH00015: Unable to open logs
May 25 15:34:28 neuron07ubtx apache2[1151]: Action 'start' failed.
May 25 15:34:28 neuron07ubtx apache2[1151]: The Apache error log may have more information.
May 25 15:34:28 neuron07ubtx apache2[1151]:  *
May 25 15:34:28 neuron07ubtx apache2[1171]:  * Stopping Apache httpd web server apache2
May 25 15:34:28 neuron07ubtx apache2[1171]:  *
May 25 15:34:28 neuron07ubtx systemd[1]: Started LSB: Apache2 web server.
```

But where can I change the port NGINX should listen??
I've tried to se it in gitlab.rb:

```
 nginx['listen_port'] = 30080
 nginx['listen_https'] = 30443
```

but it has no effect

Comment: Did you restart the Gitlab service after the config change?

Comment: It's best to give GitLab its own VM, not share it with other web sites. It can be resource intensive, especially after your teams start using it heavily.

Comment: @MichaelHampton Yes... I have had to remove it. The installation package is not done to live with other apps in the same server. Too many problems